# Quickfix Python issue with message sequence numbers between heartbeat and order event

Tags: python, quickfix

I currently have a script running using the Python version of Quickfix, in order to connect to a counterparty to send and receive FIX protocol messages.  I successfully connect, logon and send regular heartbeat messages, with the relevant outgoing and incoming messages incrementing their respective message sequence numbers in the correct manner.

I am looking to create a loop whereby I query a DB to determine whether any new orders have arrived.  Once they do appear, an order request is then sent to the counterparty.

The issue arises when the order event is triggered.  The message sequence number for my outgoing message ends up being the same as the subsequent heartbest outgoing message (which seems to get triggered at exactly the same time.  See below for snippet of issue:

**Message type Order:**

2021-06-28 15:40:12.018_699 [3370-4e4ea14a:7955d73cf3:189] (INFO) Receiving : 8=FIX.4.4|9=214|**35=D**|**34=189**|49=xxxx|52=20210628-14:40:12.016|56=xxxx|11=dzjtufgnmyy|15=EUR|22=4|38=5000|40=1|48=XS2058749925|54=1|55=N/A|60=20210628-14:40:12|115=3423581|423=1|453=1|448=210057308|447=D|452=7|537=1|10=002|

**Message type Heartbeat:**

2021-06-28 15:40:12.059_849 [3370-4e4ea14a:7955d73d1c:189] (DEBUG) Receiving : 8=FIX.4.4|9=87|**35=0**|**34=189**|49=xxxx|52=20210628-14:40:12.003|56=xxxx|112=synchronized?|10=252|

This is how I start the session, I am the acceptor, running through a thread:

```
class Threading(object):
  def __init__(self, interval=1):
    self.interval = interval

    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

def run(self):
    while True:
      settings = fix.SessionSettings(fileName)
      application = Application()
      storeFactory = fix.FileStoreFactory(settings)
      logFactory = fix.ScreenLogFactory(settings)
      acceptor = fix.SocketAcceptor(application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory)
      acceptor.start()
      print("Started acceptor")
```

I need to poll the database on a regular basis, so I chose on each heartbeat (every 30 seconds), to run a function.  I delay for 5 seconds so as to try and avoid sending the order at same time as heartbeat message (obviously not working!).

Here is the code for the script to poll the database:

```
def toAdmin(self, message, sessionID):
  print("toAdmin")
  if db_MsgType_fieldvalue == '0':
      time.sleep(5)
      self.checkDB(sessionID)
```

Finally, here is the code for when the database gets queried and when the message gets sent:

```
  def checkDB(self, sessionID):
    print("Start test trade")
    fixtradesdf = pd.read_sql_query("Select * from database where ordstatus = '0'",engine)

    for index, row in fixtradesdf.iterrows():
        message = fix.Message();  
        header = message.getHeader();
        header.setField(fix.BeginString("FIX.4.4"))
        header.setField(fix.BodyLength(137))
        header.setField(fix.MsgType("D"))
        header.setField(fix.SenderCompID("xxxx"))
        header.setField(fix.TargetCompID("xxxx"))
        header.setField(fix.SendingTime())

        message.setField(fix.ClOrdID("xxxx"))
        message.setField(fix.Symbol("N/A"))

        if row['side'] == 'BUY':
          side = fix.Side_BUY
        else:
          side = fix.Side_SELL
        message.setField(fix.Side(side))
        message.setField(fix.TransactTime())
        message.setField(fix.OrderQty(orderqty))
        message.setField(fix.Currency("EUR"))
        message.setField(fix.SecurityID("XXXX"))
        message.setField(fix.SecurityIDSource("4"))
        message.setField(fix.OrdType(fix.OrdType_MARKET))
        message.setField(fix.PriceType(1))
        message.setField(fix.QuoteType(1))

        group = fix.Group(453,448)
        group.setField(fix.PartyID("XXXX"))
        group.setField(fix.PartyIDSource("D"))
        group.setField(fix.PartyRole(7))

        message.addGroup(group)
        message.setField(fix.OnBehalfOfCompID("XXXX"))

        fix.Session.sendToTarget(message, sessionID)
```

Any ideas how I can send the order message, without duplicating the message sequence number and hence breaking the connection?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `sleep`? I think this delays the message processing inside of QF that's why your Heartbeat still gets sent at the same time.

Comment: Good suggestion, and one I tried previously, with no success unfortunately.  Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Then please kick off a new thread in toAdmin and let that sleep instead of sleeping in the callback.

Comment: Still no luck doing it that way either.